# Is it possible to search when the file is opened using tail -f option

Tags: linux

I opened a log file using tail -f mylog.log , can i do a search for a particular string during this time ??

Means when  the application is running , and i opened the log using the tail command , is it possible to search for a particular key in that log ??

Thanks

Comment: Search in the output (such as with `:` + `/word`)? Unlikely. Otherwise see the answers. In short, your question is a bit vague :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output

please refer this link. it may be helpful

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `tail` can do this.

Instead of `tail -f`, use `less +F` which has the same behaviour. Then you can press `Ctrl+C` to stop tailing and use `?` to search backwards. To continue tailing the file from within `less`, press `F`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if the file can be read by another process, yes, it can. In other words, if, for example, you search the file from another shell instance, it will work even while another instance is tail -f'ing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Pipe it into grep.

```
tail -f | grep searchstring
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question , i already opened the file and in that running file , i want to search for a word .